# StreamReader и кодировка

Tags: c#, кодировка

Допустим, у меня есть файл и у него может быть любая кодировка. Как с помощью StreamReader корректно прочитать данные из этого файла, чтобы потом записать их в другой файл с кодировкой UTF-8?

Comment: Кодировка входного файла известна / вводится пользователем?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Никак. Гарантировано рабочего решения не существует. Для того, чтобы работать с текстовым файлом, система *обязана* знать его кодировку.

Что вы можете попробовать:

1. Используйте `StreamReader` без указания кодировки. Он попробует продетектировать, и  в нормальных случаях (а это означает обычно Unicode-кодировки) ему это удаётся.
2. Попробуйте сдетектировать кодировку на основе частотного анализа. Если вам известен язык, на котором написан ваш текст, вы можете определить относительную частоту символов в текстах (это будет *ожидаемое* распределение частот), попробовать пооткрывать текст в кодировках, релевантных для этого языка (например, для русского языка это CP1251, CP866, KOI8-R и т. п.), и посмотреть, в какой из них распределение частот символов будет ближе всего к той самой относительной частоте. (Это реализовано, например, в редакторе Far Manager'а).

В ответах на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1025332/276994) есть несколько примеров с кодом, комбинирующих эти подходы.

В любом случае, на будущее: текст не имеет права храниться без кодировки. Текст без кодировки — никому не нужные данные. Всегда знайте кодировку, в которой лежит ваш текст.

---

Если же вы **знаете** кодировку файла, то всё гораздо проще:

```
var srcEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
var dstEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

using (var src = new StreamReader(srcFileName, encoding: srcEncoding))
using (var dst = new StreamWriter(dstFileName, append: false, encoding: dstEncoding))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = src.ReadLine()) != null)
        dst.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в начале файла не проставлены теги кодировок, то однозначно определить кодировку нельзя, т.е. вам понадобиться указать кодировку в аргументе `encoding`.

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
using (var src = new StreamReader(filePath, encoding: encoding))
{

}
```

Или же вы можете воспользоваться алгоритмами, которые определяют кодировку по содержанию файла. Но надо учитывать, что они не дают 100% результата.

Одним из эффективных алгоритмов является [Mozilla Universal Charset Detector](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html). Одну из его реализаций на c# вы можете найти на [github](https://github.com/linquize/ude).