# Показываются символы ???? при написании текста в файле на кириллице

Tags: c#, .net-7

У меня есть строка:
`string text = "Тест";`

Я сделал свой собственный класс, который позволяет писать и читать файл посимвольно (FileStream, StreamWriter, StreamReader) и не планировал в принципе глубоко работать с кодировкой

Индексатор для чтения:

```
public char this[long position]
{
    get
    {
        _stream.Position = position;
        return (char)_reader.Read();
    }
    set
    {
        _stream.Position = position;
        _writer.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Когда записываю всю строку в файл, там такой результат: `ллЛЛѓ`
Если этот текст считать с помощью Console.WriteLine, будет это: `???т?`

А планируется всё-таки получить "Тест"

Инициализировал _reader и _writer с разными Encoding. Все перепробовал: ASCII, Unicode, Default, UTF8

Пытался вручную перекодировать из одной в другую кодировки внутри set-ера, но не понял, какая сейчас кодировка, и какая нужна. В итоге он выбивал ошибку при перекодировании

Как можно сделать это правильным способом?

Comment: Если это винда, то кодировка там `cp1251`, в ней надо писать. Причём, и сам код где у вас написан этот "Тест" тоже должен быть в той же кодировке. Ну и учтите, что юникод - он не однобайтовый, вдруг вы побайтово читаете-пишете, тогда точно ерунда будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я читаю и пишу посимвольно
Про метод, который вы указали, хотел бы узнать побольше, поскольку не понял, что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Можете прочитать тут например примеры кода, как задать кодировку `cp1251` для чтения или записи:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417517/260769 Посимвольно - нормально, главное что не побайтово. Символы могут быть многобайтовые, это нормально обрабатывается ридерами-райтерами. Но всё же проверьте, в какой кодировке ваш код, собственно. И какая у вас система вы так и не сказали.

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня Windows 10. Файлы создаются с помощью кода (`File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)`)
Если не ошибаюсь, по умолчанию создаются ANSI файлы. В Notepad разные кодировки переключал, на ANSI будет так: "РРСС‚". Если подразумевается кодировка string текста, то Visual Studio пишет, что UTF-16

Comment: @Максим `File.ЧтоТоТам` работает с двоичными файлами, с байтами, а не с текстом. Для работы с байтами кодировки не применимы. То есть надо научиться различать классы `FileStream` для байт и `TextReader`/`TextWriter` дл текста. `StreamReader` это наследник `TextReader`, если что.

Comment: UTF-32 в помощь. Любой символ будет занимать одинаковое количество байтов: 4.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov разве нет юникод-комбинаций длиной более 4 байт? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Position` это в байтах, верно? А символ в кодировке UTF-8 сколько байт занимает?

Правильно, 1 и более байт. Кириллица гарантированно больше одного байта символ занимает, обычно два. Вот и получается, что позиция в файле к примеру 15 байт, то это 7,5 символ при условии, что перед позицией только киррилические символы. Если среди них есть например пробел, который занимает не 2 а 1 байт, то это 8 символ. То есть в многобайтовой кодировке расчитать позицию символа в файле непросуммировав длины всех предыдущих символов, условно невозможно.

Единственный вариант, при котором этот код может работать - это использование однобайтоаой кодировки, а их я знаю две: Windows-1251 и Codepage 866 (непопулярные типа KOI-8R в пример не привожу).

С другой стороны, все киррилические однобайтовые кодировки уже давно устарели и использовать их - сомнительное удовольствие.

Итого, проблемы с показанным индексатором нет при условии использования однобайтовой кодировки. В противном случае по длине `байт != символ`, отсюда вся математика.

---

Чтобы получить "Тест" в кодировке UTF-8, надо записать буквы на 0, 2, 4 и 6 позиции соответственно.

Затем переключить кодировку консоли

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UT8;
```

И вывести байты файла. Слово "Тест" отобразится корректно.

Кстати, бывает UTF-8 с BOM и без BOM (двухбайтовый префикс кодировки в начале файла). Для `StreamWriter` разница есть. Последний создаётся так: `new UTF8Encoding(false)`

Чтобы получить нестандартную кодировку в .NET 7, нужно при старте приложения выполнить один раз

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

А затем в любое время получить кодировку

```
Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
```

---

Как можно объехать проблему: взять файл, записанный в кодировке UTF-8. Прочитать его целиком в строку.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Преобразовать в массив символов

```
char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();
```

Заменить в массиве нужные символы и преобразовать обратно в строку

```
string result = new string(chars);
```

И потом записать обратно в файл целиком

```
File.WriteAllText(path, result);
```

Условно, если размер файла до 100 мегабайт, работать будет нормально.

**По умолчанию все текстовые операции с файлами выполняются в кодировке UTF-8.**

Comment: Пробовал позицию умножать на 2, не помогало. В документации Microsoft не указано, на что конкретно указывает Position
Пробовал добавлять `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)`, у меня пишет ошибку, что такая кодировка не найдена
Когда делаю `Console.OutputEncoding = UTF8`, знаки вопроса (????) заменяются красивыми (���) :)
А версия .Net: 7.0

Visual Studio пишет, что у текста UTF-16
Notepad, что файл создаётся, как ANSI
Из одного в другое пробовал перекодировать, не получалось, либо были ошибки

Comment: @Максим дополнил ответ возможным решением задачи.

Comment: Можно utf16 использовать - она не совсем устарела.

Comment: @Qwertiy в теории да, на практике детальный смысл происхощящего важен. Если просто поиграться, то сойдёт `Encoding.Unicode` и по 2 байта шагать.

Comment: Я в Си разрабатываю в CodeBlocks. вначале я ставил в консольных приложениях system("chcp 1251"); и подобное. Консоль всегда выводит в ASCII 866 кодовой странице. И в настройках редактора есть настройка, текст в кодировке 866. И не нужно потом писать разные system("chcp 1251") , что-то конвертировать. Просто пишешь сразу в кодировке консоли.
Ну а если источник текста HTML или файл, кодировках кириллицы, то написал процедурку конвертирования из одного в другое. В вики есть описание кодировок с кодами символов. И легко написать свой конвертер. Ибо часто пишу консольку а источник WEB или файлы.

Comment: @FrancNet во-первых здесь речь не про Си, а про C#. Во-вторых не про вывод в консоль вовсе. Строки в C# хранятся в кодировке UTF-16, а консоль по умолчанию в кодировке CP866. Вывод работает без каких-либо преобразований корректно, за исключением символов юникода, не поддерживаемых в CP866. `?` появляются, когда выводишь неподдерживаемый символ. Как переключить консоль в режим юникода в ответе показано. Всё остальное - ограничения шрифтов, используемых для консоли. И я не понял вообще, о чём вы, перечитайте вопрос, он про работу с файлами в юникод-кодировках, а не про консоль.